# French Apple TV apps from the US?

Tags: appletv, language

Can the 4th gen Apple TV access apps/videos in different languages?   Using the 3rd version of Apple TV I'm not aware of how you can access for instance Disney Jr Francais.  Can the fourth generation do this?

Answer (score 1):

AppleTV is multilingual. Mine is configured in german. Unfortunately I don't know the **Disney Jr Francais**.